# How to do ClojureScript editor integration with shadow-cljs and vim-fireplace

Tags: clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, shadow-cljs

If we want to do editor integration with figwheel and vim-fireplace, we need to use piggieback. The document in [piggieback](https://github.com/nrepl/piggieback) is enough to setup it. However, it seems quite difficult to setup shadow-cljs and vim-fireplace because there is no document about this and there is no example.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at reference at [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/bmz6de/luminus_shadowcljs_support/) and source code of [shadow-cljs](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs/blob/master/src/main/shadow/cljs/devtools/server/fake_piggieback.clj#L24).

To make vim-fireplace invoke ClojureScript session through nrepl at the shadow-cljs case:

1. We **do not** need to setup nrepl middleware like `:nrepl-middleware [cider.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]`
2. At vim, give the command
       `:Piggieback :client-app`

Note that: `:client-app` is the build-id of your shadow-cljs application